# Django admin. list more than 1 model together in same listing

Tags: django, django-admin

Say if I have 3 models - bananas, oranges and apples as below.

```
#models.py
class banana(fruit):
    pass
class apple(fruit):
    pass
class orange(fruit):
    pass

class fruit (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length="150")
    is_rotten = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract=True
```

In admin, I would like to display all the fruits together in a list, but with the is_rotten displayed as an editable checkbox so it's possible to view all fruits together and mass assign the is_rotten variable.

```
class fruitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    list_display = ('title', 'is_rotten')
    list_editable = ('is_rotten',)
```

I've got this far but seaching around multiple models in same admin list isn't bringing anything up.  Is it possible to create the listing i am envisaging?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a table for `fruit` or another table relating all fruits with their properties (`title` and `is_rotten`). With your models as you wrote them, **you can't do that**, since Django `admin` doesn't support registering for **abstract** classes.

So if you change your `fruit` class to:

```
class fruit (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length="150")
    is_rotten = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Keep the other models as you wrote them:

```
class banana(fruit):
    pass

class apple(fruit):
    pass

class orange(fruit):
    pass
```

And add this to your `your_app/admin.py` module:

```
class FruitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("title", "is_rotten")

admin.site.register(myapp.models.fruit, FruitAdmin)
```

Usnig this code you get a list as shown in image below:

[image]

Comment: Ha, that's true but i need the 3 separate models.  Of course doing it as you state is possible but it's not a solution to refactor the models based on how i want the admin to look.  Having mulled over this today, I think maybe a model manager might be the way to go

Comment: I don't meant you have to delete the other models. The only change I made to your models was to turn`Fruit` into `no-abstract` class.

Comment: In the image I posted, `Apple 1` and `Apple 2` are actually instances of the model `apple`. The same for `Orange 1`, `Banana 1` and `Banana 2`. None of them are direct instances of `fruit` class.

Comment: Yes you're right, but like that, the database would have a redundant fruit table and then 3 tables for each of the fruits.

Comment: Any way you will need a fourth table. You can call it `fruit`, `FruitProperties`, whatever, but this table have to exist in the database. Django admin application **don't allow the registration of abstract or non-model clases.**

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, i suppose the answer is that i need to rethink the problem.